# What Greyhawk deity is this?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, religions-and-deities, greyhawk

I was doing my weekly browsing of the paizo forums, when [this post](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs43b8b?Cleric-Spells-are-they-kept-without-praying#7) caught my eye.

> Greyhawk deity that was published in a number of the Dragon magazine. Her portfolio includes comfortable life, her church floor is covered by pillows and the priests feel that sleeping while they do mass is a show of faith and appreciation for the priest.

I'm not familiar with the Greyhawk setting, but given my amusement with this god I'm considering converting them over for my Pathfinder campaign. Can anyone tell me what god this is and give me more information about them so I can do so?

<sub>Note: this has the [dungeons-and-dragons](/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) tag, because I'm not sure what edition they're from, or if they feature in multiple.</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is likely Sotillion, the Summer Queen, Queen of Ease. She was not solely *Dragon* material, though she was mentioned at the very least in vol. 264. Based on the earliest citation on [this ghwiki page](https://ghwiki.greyparticle.com/index.php/Sotillion), which seems to be the most thorough out there, her debut was 1983’s *World of Greyhawk Fantasy Game Setting*. That page also cites a number of publications by both TSR and Wizards of the Coast, though none since 2005 (i.e. nothing in 4e or 5e), and the 2005 citation was just that she was included in the list of valid Greyhawk deities for the purposes of the Living Greyhawk campaign.

Mention of her faithful falling asleep during services as an act of piety can be found on the Internet, e.g. on the aforementioned ghwiki page, though I haven’t found a solid source for this among canonical sources (then again, I don’t own most of them to check).

[This page](http://hastur.net/wiki/Sotillion_(Greyhawk_Action)) seems to have some suggestions for how to portray her faithful in Pathfinder, assigning her a few cleric domains and a couple of religious traits, as well as describing an “obedience” through which one can get a minor boon from her.

Answer (score 7):

This would be the goddess Sotillion, Lady Harvest, Queen of Ease. While having been mentioned as early as 1983 in the World of Greyhawk Fantasy Game Setting, there has been an article about her in Dragon No. 264, p. 48-50: The Oeridian Lesser Gods (Andy Miller).

> Temples to the deity are very plush and comfortable. There are no benches and hard pews in such temples. Instead well-padded chairs of the most comfortable (though not necessarily most expensive) fabrics stand in the worship hall. (...) Some temples even forgo furniture alltogether, relying instead in matresses and blankets on the floor and allowing their worshippers to relax however they want. (Dragon 264, p.49).

Sotillion is the goddess of the harvest and the bringer of summer. She is depicted as "the embodiment of laziness".

Comment: I wonder how "harvest" and "laziness" mix together.

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO "Sotillion is the wife of Zilchus [god of trade and commerce], whose prosperity allows her to retain her favorite comforts."  She is a Queen - the labor of others allows her to enjoy the bounty of the harvest without having had to work to bring it in.  In other words, "Summertime, and the living is easy. / Fish are jumping, and the cotton is high. /
Oh, your daddy's rich, and your ma is good-looking. / So, hush, little baby, don't you cry."